# My loop variable resets to true even though the loop should stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have a `while` loop that worked fine in previous versions of python.  Now the loop variable seems to get reset.
Keep in mind I do this just as a hobby so if there is another/better way to achieve my result - Feel free.

So this code has a list of numbers and compares them to another list.  If the `num` in `numbers` is not present in the other list it is removed. and the process is restarted.  Problem is that once the lists match the loop variable still gets reset to `True` and the it code is stuck in a loop:

```
loop = True
def remove_games():
    for num in numbers:
        loop = False
        if int(num) in df.game_number.values:
            continue
        else:
            idx = numbers.index(num)
            numbers.remove(num)
            games.pop(idx)
            loop = True
            num=''
            break

while loop:
    remove_games()
```

Comment: You need to add `global loop` to the top of `remove_games`.  Otherwise `loop` is local inside of `remove_games`.

Comment: None of this works the way you seem to think. The `while` loop is pointless because you have a `for` loop doing the work already. Setting the loop variable `num = ''` does nothing. Etc..

Comment: In which python version does that code not raise `NameError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loop` in `remove_games` is a local variable. I'm not sure in which version of Python could this work, but declaring `global loop` in `remove_games` should give you the behavior you want.

On the other hand, it's not elegant to use a global variable in cases where a return value suffices. So I would do something like this:

```
def remove_games():
    for num in numbers:
        if int(num) in df.game_number.values:
            continue
        else:
            idx = numbers.index(num)
            numbers.remove(num)
            games.pop(idx)
            num=''
            return True
    return False


while remove_games():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using a [difference of sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference_update):

```
nums = set(map(int, numbers))
nums -= df.game_number
```

The only potential problem here is that `set` is not an ordered collection. You can iterate through `nums`, but the order is arbitrary. If numbers had an important order originally, you can use a `dict` instead of a `set` as of CPython 3.6 (where it was still an "implementation detail", fully adopted in 3.7). For prior versions, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
nums = dict.from_keys(map(int, numbers))
numbers = list(nums.keys() - df.game_number)
```

Comment: OP also needs to remove corresponding indices from `games`, so the `dict` option might be the best anyway. Although the ultimate answer might be that "your data structure is wrong --- you should be using `dict` from the very beginning".

Comment: @Imperishable. That OP is using the wrong data structure is almost a given here. I just don't want to open that can of worms without further information. Any suggestions I make beyond the immediate question are likely going to be wrong as well.